# Nice convergent subsequence of $\cos(n)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

This question is related to a few questions which have been posted on the website :

- [Is there a limit of $\cos(n!)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/is-there-a-limit-of-cos-n)
- [Converging subsequence on a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42355/converging-subsequence-on-a-circle)
- [The limit of $\sin(n!)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677719/the-limit-of-sinn)

Because of the irrationality of $\pi$, the sequence $(\cos(n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is dense in $[-1;1]$. For any value $a\in[-1;1]$, we can extract a subsequence $(\cos(n_k))_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ convergent to $a$.

My question is the following:
Does someone know an example of a convergent subsequence of $\cos(n)$ with an *explicit expression*?

Some more comments:

We could define a subsequence in the following way:
$$n_0=1;\quad n_{k+1}>n_k \text{ such that } |\cos(n_k)-a|<1/k.$$
This subsequence is well defined (and unique if we add the condition that $n_{k+1}$ should be minimum) and converges. But I would say, that this not explicit.
I don't have a definition of what should be an explicit expression, and any answer are welcome.

Reading the nice answer of David Speyer in [Is there a limit of $\cos(n!)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/is-there-a-limit-of-cos-n), it seems that we still don't understand enough about $\pi$ to proof or disprove that $\cos(n!)$ diverges.
Because of these comments, I would not be surprised if the answer to my question is no.

Comment: Does "$n_k$ is the numerator of the $k^{\rm th}$ convergent in the continued fraction expansion of $2\pi$" count as an explicit expression?

Comment: @Micah, no. Then I would post a new question: Dos someone knows an explicit expression of "$n_k$, the numerator of the $k^{th}$ convergent in the continued fraction expansion of $2\pi$"? ;-)
I am looking for something more "explicit".